# sqlite3.OperationalError: undefined symbol: sqlite3_json_init

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have installed the `JSON1` extension for `sqlite3` with Python.

I connect to the database with: `conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH)`

And when I try to load the extension with `conn.load_extenstion(PATH_TO_EXTENSION)`. I get the following error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: /home/shtlrs/chrisJ_property_database/json_ext/json1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_json_init

The problem is that it runs on my PC, but when I try to run it on my other laptop, it gives me that error.

Comment: Is the extension installed and enabled on the other laptop?

Comment: Yes I guess, since it works. I remember compiling it and doing a lot of stuff to make it work because I was having a problem with the compilation. But I really forgot what I had done precisely